# Performing a one to many join in R dplyr

Tags: join, dplyr

How to do a one to one-to-many join without any keysin r using `dplyr`?
I have two tables:

```
origin<-tribble(~"o",
     1,2)

destination<-tribble(~"d",
     5,
     6,
     7)
```

I want to merge both of them without any keys like the following:

```
od<- tribble(~"o",~"d",
        1,5,
        1,6,
        1,7,
        2,5,
        2,6,
        2,7)
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` and `rep` to repeat the rows in `origin` based on the length of `destination`. Then, inside of `bind_cols`, we can create a list and repeat the values in `destination` based on the length of `origin`; then, bind them together.

```
library(tidyverse)

origin %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = nrow(destination[, 1]))) %>%
  bind_cols(., d = unlist(rep(
    c(destination[, 1]), times = nrow(origin)
  )))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
      o     d
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     5
2     1     6
3     1     7
4     2     5
5     2     6
6     2     7
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::crossing` and `expand_grid` can give you a cross join of two dataframes.

```
tidyr::crossing(origin, destination)
#tidyr::expand_grid(origin, destination)

#     o     d
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     5
#2     1     6
#3     1     7
#4     2     5
#5     2     6
#6     2     7
```